# How to create a histogram with specified Bins and Values in matplotlib?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, histogram

matplotlib == 3.6.2
python == 3.9.15

I'm trying to create a historgram however I've already pre-computed the heights of each bin as a percentage.

Data Example

```py
values=[0.5, 0.25, 0.25]
bins=[0.0, 1.0, 5.0, 7.0]
```

Histograms seem to wanted the raw dataset and I do not have that. Bar charts will let me set the height, but I can't specify varying bin values (which makes sense because bar charts don't have bins, histograms do).

Thoughts?

Comment: My thought is that I don't quite understand what exactly you are trying to achieve and your question would be improved by an example of the expected result.

Comment: Make a bar chart, and then label each bar based on the corresponding bin.

Comment: `plt.bar(bins[:-1], values, width=np.diff(bins), align='edge', ec='white')`